# What happens to signal handler after exec call?

Tags: c

A signal handler installed by a parent process is preserved by the fork() (the child process inherits the handler) but what happens when a process does an exec call ?

The handlers that the process has are **maintained** or do they **disappear** ?

Comment: *fork* is a duplication of the process, *exec* is a replacement by another program, thus no specific handler from the previous process remain when the new one runs.

Comment: It can't possibly be preserved. The process's memory, including the code for the handler, gets replaced by `exec`.